# Microsoft MPEG-2 Encoder & MPEG-2 Video Encoder failed at Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, directshow, mpeg-2

During building record graph to file from video and audio sources using Microsoft MPEG-2 Encoder at Windows 8 ICaptureGraphBuilder2::SetOutputFileName return failed 80040154 result - class not registred.

```
    //Adding MPEG2 Encoder Muxer filter to the graph
hr = m_pCapGraphBuilder->SetOutputFileName(&CLSID_CMPEG2EncoderDS, szOutFileName, &pMPEG2EncoderMuxer, &pFileSinkFilter);
```

Also at graphedit any attempt to insert at graph MPEG-2 Encoder & MPEG-2 Video Encoder filter failed with description:
"The filter could not be created. Resourses used by this filter may alreadey be in use. (Return code: 0xc004f011) "

Why this happen and how to avoid this problem?

Will be happy for any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your windows 8 has a MPEG-2 encoder? As I heard from MS, they removed MPEG-2 from Windows 8 and you must buy an encoder by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but the fact, what filters are listed how directshow filters at official tool and doesn't work, little suprised me.

Comment: 0xC004F011 = SL_E_LICENSE_FILE_NOT_INSTALLED. Maybe if you buy the MediaCenter pack the License is activated and this filter can be used.